# Would android women be a better companionship and better sex partners for men than "real" women?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, science-fiction, culture, robots

If robotics become advanced enough for the creation of humanlike androids( mentally and physically indistinguishable from flesh and blood humans) become possible in an affordable way for the average person would most men choose to create their robotic women rather than choose the biological females for sex, companionship and friendship? ( of course women should be able to create male androids if they wanted) considering that these men don't want to have children?

How would society change? Would most humans accept this or would a phobia and a stigma against lifelike robots develop among many people?

Comment: Since androids would likely tolerate treatment (whether sexual or simple neglect outside the bedroom) that an actual human would not and would also be likely be far less expensive to maintain (once paid for) I do suspect there would be a ready market for such a product. There might well be an uncanny valley phase where they aren't quite there but once they pass that point, well ...

Comment: Most of time, phrases such as "how would [society/global views/human history/etc] change as a result of x" tend to be too broad for this site. The situation you describe is potentially one giant cane of worms regarding the rights of sapient manufactured beings, the risk of assassinations through super strong human robots, movements against "machine slavery" and against the existence of said machines are all potential things that could exist along with such robots and the list goes on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"indistinguishable mentally and physically"*? If there was no way to tell a "human" from an "android" don't you essentially just have humans?

Comment: Some additional factors: How long have these androids been available? (a year, a decade, a century, etc) How much do they cost (in other words, who can actually have them). And then figure that cost/availability changes over time. As do society's attitudes. So time is important. You could write a whole history of how this changes from one decade to the next.

Comment: If the androids are "*mentally ... indistinguishable from flesh and blood humans*", they would deserve all the civil liberties (and responsibilities) afforded to all humans and could therefore legally and morally refuse to provide the companionship commanded of them.  They could also potentially develop any type of personality defect, antisocial tendency, and mental health issue a human would.  So what would be the point of creating one of these?

Comment: If the bots are indistinguishable from people, then they are people. But if those bots are custom made, they would not be mentally equal to human women. They would be droid hookers, because the kind of man that would invest resources on that is the kind of incel that plays erotic dating simulators in real life.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw  I think you vastly underestimate the ability of the teenage male to think with the wrong head, particular when tempted by something that offers to fulfil their every fantasy.  And once on that path, there's no turning back.

Comment: Read of watch the [*Stepford Wives*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stepford_Wives).

Comment: Better still, read the Murderbot Diaries

Comment: In a future where population fell a lot due to war or very low birth rates androids could be useful to increase world's population. Besides it would be the dream of many roboticists to create them.

Answer (score 4):

## Society would trade in real women in a heartbeat

We live in an age of instant gratification. Though gratification is a bit of a misnomer, as it doesn't mean we're actually happy. We hope for likes and comments, can instantly check things that align with what we think and when anonymous many start misbehaving.

This isn't exactly our fault. Algorithms and advertising steer and manipulate us constantly. This happens more and more without human intervention. They make people addicted with things that only momentarily make you happy, so you come back just a bit later for a new fix.

Now introduce female androids. Instant gratification? Check. Can do whatever you want? Check. Says what you want to hear? Check.

No hassle and instant gratification will make the majority never reconsider. Even if this makes them unhappy overall, the most often small and temporary boosts will make them addicted to an android woman quickly enough.

Stigma will arrive, but it'll not be able to stop them. History has shown time and time again that many will choose destructive behaviour just to be happy or feel in control. Cigarettes? Unhealthy food bans? Gun control in the USA or touching their gas guzzling cars? The majority of cosmetic surgery? It doesn't matter. Too soon it'll be accepted, or defended so vehemently that it's impossible to stop.

Comment: Maybe add that it goes both directions? It's probably not just men trading in women, but also the other way around. Might even be people trading in family, friends, everything else.

Comment: As a woman, I would trade real men around me for androids even faster than men can replace me. My house will be finally clean, everything will be working, and no f-ing snoring! I will also save a lot of money in the process: Androids don't have expensive hobbies, do they?

Comment: The majority of humankind is female, by a small margin.